# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS identifying Wireless/Lan but will not connect

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, network-manager

Just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my newly built machine.

TP-Link TL-WDN4800 PCI Express Wifi Adapter
Gigabyte 970A-D3P Mobo,
MSI R7 265 GPU,
blah blah blah.

Anyway. When I first booted, Ubuntu gave me the option to connect to the internet to have the latest version of the install.  My connection was recognized but I could not proceed forward with the installation at that point, so I continued without a connection.

My wireless connection is found/recognized but I cannot for the life of me connect to it.  I've tried connecting to my lan but no to no avail there either.

Running ifconfig displays statuses for eth0, lo, and wlan0.
 iwconfig shows:

`eth0   no wireless extensions.
 lo     no wireless extensions.
 wlan0  IEEE 802.11abgn   ESSID:off/any
 Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated  Tx-Power=20dBm
 Retry long limit:7  RTS thr: off   Fragment thr:off
 Power Management: off`

I've tried running `service network-manager restart` as well.

I cannot seem to find any Linux drivers for this particular card.  I've had this issue in the past with a laptop that had Ubuntu 12.01 on it but I cannot for the life of me remember how I resolved it.

Please give me a hand and let me use this new box to its fullest potential!

Comment: apologies for any typo's, had to copy the terminal output by hand :)

Answer (score 0):

According to TP-Link your card supports Linux with the Atheros9k (ath, ath_9k modules) driver. This should come default on an Ubuntu installation. I am using an Atheros card and it works flawlessly.

from a command line try:

lsmod|grep ath

and you should see something like this:

```
ath3k                  13318  0 
bluetooth             395387  28 bnep,hidp,ath3k,btusb,rfcomm
ath9k                 164164  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              638933  1 ath9k
cfg80211              496328  3 ath,ath9k,mac80211
```

If not then the module is either not loading or the wrong one is for some reason.

The output you posted is from iwconfig, not from ifconfig. However the fact that your device shows up means that it is recognized and the driver is loading.

The fact that neither wired or wireless works makes me think something is up with your network manager, router/local network, o,r maybe BIOS settings (probably not). Try rebooting the router and ensuring that all the settings there are OK. Make sure DHCP is enabled and/or try connecting with a static IP. Also try with and without encryption on your router. Finally you can try enabling 2.4ghz and disabling 5ghz, and/or try vise-versa to see if that works.

Atheros is well supported in Linux and should work out of the box.

You can get more information with the following commands:

```
lspci -vv -s
dmesg
ifconfig
rfkill list all
```

You can disable hardware encryption and see if that helps:

```
echo "options ath9k nohwcrypt=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath9k.conf options ath9k nohwcrypt=1

sudo modprobe -rfv ath9k
```

I have also found that on a fresh install DNS is wonky sometimes. As root, edit the file /etc/resolv.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

and add the following lines.

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

Save the file and try again. More info here:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/resolv.conf

Comment: Thank you for the response Joshua!

The `lsmod|grep ath` command yielded all similar information to what you have (small differences with the metrics in the second column.

My wireless is successfully establishing a connection, however when attempting to navigate web pages, my browser hangs.

Also, while trying to run `sudo apt-get update`, I cannot seem to connect to any of the repositories listed.

I've tried resetting my router to establish clean settings, but to no avail.  Any other suggestions would be appreciated, I'll keep at it until then.  Thank you again!

Comment: Try adding the openDNS servers in your /etc/resolv.conf file... sounds like you are not resolving for some reason. See my edit above.

Comment: I am trying to add the `nameserver` lines to the resolv.conf file as sudo through nano, however my changes do not save, they seem to keep being overridden (which there is a description in the file that is telling me it will do just that.)  There is however a new `resolv.conf~` file that is appearing in the same directory, that DOES contain the nameserver IPs

Is there anymore output that I can provide to you that will be beneficial?

Comment: Update:

Although it took about 5-10 minutes, Google's homepage loaded for me this morning.  It still timed out after trying to search or navigate to another page.  `sudo apt-get update` is still failing to fetch at all URL's.  After the timeout my wireless manager is immediately disconnecting from the wifi.